# How are signals different from pubsub?

Tags: python, signals, publish-subscribe, blinker

Django and Flask make use of signals — the latter uses the [Blinker](http://discorporate.us/projects/Blinker/) library. In the context of Python, [Blinker](http://discorporate.us/projects/Blinker/) and the Python [pubsub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) library, how do signals and pubsub compare? When would I use one or the other?

Comment: I'm kind of looking for a definitive answer from someone who's been down this path such as, "They're the same thing" or "PubSub usually involves X while signals usually mean Y."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Blinker docs](http://discorporate.us/projects/Blinker/docs/1.1/) and [PubSub docs](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/usage/usage_advanced_other.html#messaging-protocol).

As far as `Blinker` and `PubSub` go, they are the same thing.  The difference is in how they go about it:

With `Blinker` when you subscribe to a signal you give the name of the signal, and when you activate the signal you pass the activating object.

With `PubSub` when you subscribe to a listener you give the name (same as `Blinker`), but when you notify the listener you pass the data directly as keyword arguments.  Because of the keyword argument method of passing data, it is possible to have many more safety checks using `PubSub`.

Personally, I would go with `Blinker` as it matches my way of thinking better, but `PubSub` certainly has a place also.

Answer (score 6):

This might clear up exactly how Pubsub relates to signals: http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/apidocs/concepts.html

> Pubsub facilitates the decoupling of components (callables, modules, packages) within an application. It does this by:
>
> - Allowing parts of the application to send messages to “the rest of the application” without having to know
>
>   - *if* the messages will be handled:
>
>     - perhaps the message will be ignored completely,
>     - or handled by a many different parts of the application;
>   - *how* the messages will be handled:
>
>     - what will be done with the message and its contents;
>     - in what order any given message will be sent to the rest of the application;
> - Allowing parts of the application to receive and handle messages from “the rest of the application” without having to know who sent the messages.
>
> A listener is “a part of the application that wants to receive messages”. A listener subscribes to one or more topics. A sender is any part of the application that asks Pubsub to send a message of a given topic. The sender provides data, if any. Pubsub will send the message, including any data, to all listeners of the message’s topic.

Comment: Don't all these things apply to signals and receivers too?